Hyperref url border disappears when using \DocumentMetadata
Today I found The documentmetadata-support code and checked out \DocumentMetadata: After reading the manual I set up \DocumentMetadata as follows:
% \DocumentMetadata{
%     backend         = luatex,
%     pdfversion      = 2.0,
%     lang            = de-DE,
%     xmp             = true,
% }

\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks      = false,
    urlcolor        = {red},
    urlbordercolor  = {red},
}

\begin{document}
    \url{www.google.de}
\end{document}

For whatever reason borders (e.g. url borders) set up by hyperref disappear whenever I use \DocumentMetadata. After looking inside the manual, I find no compatibility issues or limitations regarding borders, just some info about using hyperref with a pdf standard:


Please don't link to particular CTAN mirrors, but to the primary site which redirects people to nearby mirrors.

I will change the implementation and leave pdfborder alone if colorlinks=false is used (colorlinks=true will still reset the border to 0!). Generally I would avoid to set to many unneeded options, it only clutters your source. Neither backend=luatex, nor xmp=true nor colorlinks=false is needed. And always add a protocol to an url, so \url{https://....}

The new code uses the new generic hyperref driver from the pdfresources bundle, which has some different defaults. You can re-force the solid border style using urlborderstyle
 \DocumentMetadata{
%     backend         = luatex,
     pdfversion      = 2.0,
     lang            = de-DE,
     xmp             = true,
 }

\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks      = false,
    urlcolor        = {red},
    urlbordercolor  = {red},
    urlborderstyle = {/S 1}
}

\begin{document}
    \url{www.google.de}
\end{document}



Hm I should check if the default behaviour is really the wanted one. Side remark: xmp = true is the default so not needed.

@David Carlisle Does hyperref-generic also provide a key for citations. I have tried citeborderstyle = {/Type~ /Border~ /W~ 1~ /S~ /D~ /D[3~ 2]}, but it seems there is no such key to customize citation borders.

@Dave note Ulrike decided this was a bug https://github.com/latex3/pdfresources/issues/69  as for citeborder  see ..

@Dave %   \item[cite colors] As mentioned above the support for |citecolor|
%   and |citebordercolor|   has been reduced. A package like \pkg{hyperref}
%   can't keep track of such semantic
%   contexts like cite, acronym, glossaries and special references and maintain keys for
%   them. The keys are not completly dropped as this would affect packages like
%   \pkg{natbib}, but they have been separated and are no longer affected by
%   group keys like |allcolors|  but must be set individually instead.

@David Carlisle No, I dont want to specifically color different references like cite, acronym, glossaries and special references. I want to style cite borders differently than url borders; for example url borders solid, while cite borders are dashed. Thats possible for pdfborder, linkborder, urlborder, fileborder, runborder and menuborder (see. p. 14) but somehow there is no support to edit BS dictionary of pdfs for cite borders (/BS <</Type /Border /W 1 /S /D /D[3 2]>>) even though the BS dictionary gets created in the final pdf (see next comment, no space left).

7 0 obj << /Type /Annot /Subtype /Link /Border [0 0 0] /H /I /C [0.36864 0.3098 0.63528] /BS <</Type /Border /W 1 /S /D /D[3 2]>>  /Rect [ 64.347 715.45 71.709 728.402 ]/A  << /S /GoTo /D (cite.0@test) >> >> endobj
